# How to Split Mapbox Popups Into Separate Boxes

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am running into an issue when I setup popups using the Mapbox API. The popups are merged into one massive block that extends far to long. This is because I have multiple features grouped on in one location and am selecting them all. The problem is that I want the popups to be in separate windows that I can switch between by pressing a button.

I do not have a clear understanding of my problem as my experience using JS is only at a barely basic level. I have attempted a few solutions and tried to read through the documentation on the Mapbox website, but was unable to resolve this. However, I have to get this working as the original map is years out of date and it falls on me to replace it.

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
          var bbox = [
            [e.point.x - 2, e.point.y - 2],
            [e.point.x + 2, e.point.y + 2]
          ];
          var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(bbox, {
            layers: ['2016-2018-crash-data']
          });
          var feature = features[0];

      var html = "";
      for (var f in features) {
        var feature = features[f];
        html += '<table id="popup_content" class="mdl-data-table"><center><h5>Accident Details</h5></center>' +
          '<td><strong> Year of Crash </strong></td>' +
          '<td>' + feature.properties.CRASH_YR + '</td></tr>' +
          '<tr><td><strong> Road </strong></td>' + '<td>' +
          feature.properties.ODPS_LOC_ROAD_NME + ' ' +
          feature.properties.ODPS_LOC_ROAD_SUFFIX_CD + ' ' +
          feature.properties.ODPS_LOC_ROUTE_PREFIX_CD + ' ' +
          feature.properties.ODPS_LOC_ROUTE_ID + '</td></tr>' +
          '<tr><td><strong> Light Conditions </strong></td>' + '<td>' +
          feature.properties.LIGHT_COND_PRIMARY_CD + '</td></tr>' +
          '<tr><td><strong> Crash Type </strong></td>' + '<td>' +
          feature.properties.CRASH_TYPE_CD + '</td></tr>' +
          '<tr><td><strong> Weather </strong></td>' + '<td>' +
          feature.properties.WEATHER_COND_CD + '</td></tr>' +
          '<tr><td><strong> Road Conditions </strong></td>' + '<td>' +
          feature.properties.ROAD_COND_PRIMARY_CD + ' ' +
          feature.properties.ROAD_COND_SECONDARY_CD + '</td></tr>' +
          '<tr><td><strong> Factors </strong></td>' + '<td>' +
          feature.properties.U1_CONT_CIR_PRIMARY_CD + '</td></tr>' +
          '<tr><td><strong> Vehicle Type </strong></td>' + '<td>' +
          feature.properties.U1_TYPE_OF_UNIT_CD + '</td></tr>' +
          '<tr><td><strong> Road Contour </strong></td>' + '<td>' +
          feature.properties.ROAD_CONTOUR_CD + '</td></tr>' +
          '<tr><td><strong> Serious Injuries </strong></td>' + '<td>' +
          feature.properties.ODPS_TOTAL_FATALITIES_NBR + '</td></tr>' +
          '<tr><td><strong> Fatalities </strong></td>' + '<td>' +
          feature.properties.INCAPAC_INJURIES_NBR + '</td></tr>';
      }
        var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
          offset: [0, 7]
        })

        .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
        .setHTML(message + html + buttons)
        .addTo(map);
    });
```

This is almost the entirety of the popup code. It currently has no errors and display all popups, just in a long vertically oriented list as if each feature's popup has been appended to the last.

Edit:
Currently, I have multiple data points overlapping each other. When I click on that location, it generates a popup for all of the data points in that location. I want it to generate a separate popup for each data point instead of one popup.

Here's what it looks like currently:
[Popup continues too far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeUxN.jpg)

Here's kind of what I want it to look like:
[Popup with buttons to sort through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a0jm.png)

Comment: Can you explain better what result you're looking for here?

Comment: @SteveBennett I'm trying to get multiple popups instead of one long popup. I edited my question to better demonstrate that.

Comment: I still don't really understand how that would look, or how you would "switch between by pressing a button". Are you sure that multiple popups is a good solution to your problem?

Comment: @SteveBennett I've added images to the question. Hopefully that helps. I'm not sure really how else to explain it. I think I understand how to do the buttons and switch by counting through features.length, but I'm not sure why I'm getting one popup populated with all of the feature data.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, what you want is still just one popup. You are using Mapbox-GL-JS correctly. You just need to find a way to display multiple tables worth of information using some kind of paging control, rather than one after another.

There is no direct support in Mapbox-GL-JS for something like that. You probably want to use some kind of framework (jQuery perhaps) with a plugin (perhaps https://pagination.js.org/) to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll take a look at the documentation and come back to this if it solves my problem. Just in case, I'm going to leave the question open for a little while longer.